# Do Apache NiFi's InvokeHTTP and other HTTP processors send an Authorization header to redirected URLs?

Tags: http, authorization, apache-nifi

If I have configured a property `Authorization` with a bearer token, will InvokeHTTP send that header to the *redirected* URL?

I can't find anything in the documentation about it. I also can't seem to find clarity in the source of OkHttp, the underlying library for InvokeHTTP.

Is there a way to *strip* a header from a redirected URL based on the URL?

I may quickly be getting into "use ExecuteGroovyScript" territory here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, because OkHttp [strips `Authorization` on redirects](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http/RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt#L301):

```
// When redirecting across hosts, drop all authentication headers. This
// is potentially annoying to the application layer since they have no
// way to retain them.
if (!sameConnection(userResponse, url)) {
  requestBuilder.removeHeader("Authorization");
}
```

We know this thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52285990/204052.